# UICollectionReusableView method not being called

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want my sections in the `UICollectionView` to have a header with an image.

I have followed these steps:

- at the storyboard, assigned a header as an accessory for my `UICollectionView`
- gave it an identifier
- created a subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` for it
- assigned the custom class to the class at the storyboard.
- put an `ImageView` at the header accessory
- made an outlet for the `ImageView` at the custom class in the `.h` file
- Implemented the following at `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[ScheduleHeaderView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:headerIdentifier];

-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
    {
        ScheduleHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:headerIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        headerView.headerImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"];

        reusableview = headerView;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

I know that the datasource and delegate methods are working because I can see all the cells and its sections. However, I don't have my headers. I put in a breakpoint at the method above and it's never being called.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you compare the string pointers `kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` instead of the strings contents, you probably want to use `[kind isEqualToString: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]` instead.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

It seems that you have to give your header a non-zero size or `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath` isn't called. So either set the `headerReferenceSize` property of the flow layout like so:

```
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 100.f);
```

**Swift 5+**

```
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 100))
```

or, implement `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` if you want to vary the size by section.

Comment: in collection view, can i do for dynamic height by autolayout instead of defining headerReference size?

Comment: is it possible to set headerReferenceSize in Storyboard on flowLayout?

Comment: Yes It Worked !         layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: (self.collectionView?.frame.width)!, height: 50);  for swift4

Comment: `headerReferenceSize` works but I need different sizes for different sections. And the method you specified isn't called at all

Answer (score 36):

You answered the question, but in words I understand better:

To make the method being called, add these methods:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGSizeMake(60.0f, 30.0f);
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGSizeMake(60.0f, 30.0f);
}
```

...and go from there.

Answer (score 34):

Swift 4 Xcode 9.1 Beta 2

Add @objc

```
@objc func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout  collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
    let size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 50)
    return size
}
```

Credits:
https://medium.com/@zonble/your-delegation-methods-might-not-be-called-in-swift-3-c6065ed7b4cd

Comment: Thank you! Saved my butt. Btw, I noticed this function doesn't show up in the auto-complete list for collectionViewDelegate. I don't know why, so weird. Also weird that we need the @objc tag in front of it.

Comment: Only adding @objc to the function in Swift 4 worked for me. Ridiculous.

Comment: Conforming to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout instead of UICollectionViewDelegate also fixes this without @objc if you're using UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Comment: it is a lot better if you use the collectionView bounds to set the with of your section  header/footer: 
let size = CGSize(collectionView.bounds.width, height: 50)

Answer (score 21):

Did you add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in current interface? This worked for me.

`@interface MyViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>`

Swift:

`class MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {`

Comment: Ahh! so this is it...`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3.0 (xcode 8.2.1)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:30.0)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is the swift version :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 50)
    return size
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 50)
    return size
}
```

XCode (version 7.3.1 ) does not propose these methods in autocomplete !

If you just want a header, just keep the header method.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that in swift 3, the name of the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function has changed slightly from any posts that were on stack overflow. Hence, it was never getting called. Make sure that, if you're in swift 3, you're delegate function matches:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {}
```

Comment: Mine too. For me there was a missing "_", "atIndexPath" instead of "at" and "NSIndexPath" instead of "IndexPath"; as I have copied the method from somewhere and IDE didn't give me an error.

Comment: Wow wow wow wow wow. THIS was the problem I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
    @objc (collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:)
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView { }
```

The above code worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5
Smooth and easy way

only these two line are missing in your code and you will done

use these line any where

```
let layout = self.colv.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: self.colv.frame.size.width, height: 100)
```

I am using these lines in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let CellCount = CGFloat(3.0)
    let width = CGFloat(collectionView.frame.size.width/CellCount)
    //let height = CGFloat(collectionView.frame.size.height)

    
    let layout = self.colv.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: self.colv.frame.size.width, height: 100)
    
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width+10)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I have added **`referenceSizeForFooterInSection`** but then also **`viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`** not getting called.
I have added this code in `viewDidLoad()` and it worked for me:

```
if let flowLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds = true   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, in Swift 4.2, func collectionView(collectionView:kind:indexPath:) -> UICollectionReusableView was never being called. This was for a collection view in a UIViewController.  I noticed the existing collection view functions were qualified with @objc, and that the UICollectionView had not adopted the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate protocols.  As soon as I adopted the protocols, I got errors that the collection view functions did not match the protocol.  I corrected the function syntax, removed the qualifiers, and the section headers started working.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a generic subclass then you must take care to specify ObjC delegate method name
*if it's different then Swift name (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2817).*

```
@objc (collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:)
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
...
```