# UICollectionReusableView not showing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have added `<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>` to my collection view and set up my `UICollectionView` as below.

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:headerReuseIdentifier];
```

I have also added the necessary methods.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0f);
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)supplementaryViewForElementKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"supplementaryViewForElementKind called");
    if ([elementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
        UICollectionReusableView *header = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                               withReuseIdentifier:headerReuseIdentifier
                                                                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
        header.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return header;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

However, `supplementaryViewForElementKind` never gets called. Any ideas?

Comment: did you add self.collectionView.delegate = self in viewdidload?

Comment: Yep, sorry. I forgot to add that to the question.

Comment: did you register to the delegate in the implementation uicollectionviewdelegate?

Comment: @StefanSzekeres Yes, I did. The delegate is just the `UICollectionViewController` in which I registered to `<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18174257/1889814

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the header view in Interface Builder and already assigned the class, then you should remove the `registerClass` call in your code. It should show then. Put a break in your delegate method to see it being called.